# Bash array fails to populate if function is executed as if condition

Tags: arrays, bash, if-statement, subshell

I have a function which populates a global bash array

```
#!/bin/bash

# Array to store debugger IDs
ID=()

fill_id()
{
    for i in 1 2 3 4 5
    do
        ID+=( $i )
    done

    echo "fill_ids      - entries in ID: ${#ID[*]}"
}
```

If function is called directly, array gets populated and entry count is printed as 5

```
fill_id
echo "main          - entries in ID: ${#ID[*]}"
```

Output

```
fill_ids      - entries in ID: 5
main          - entries in ID: 5
```

But if function is called in `if` condition then entry count is printing as 0

```
if (fill_id)
then
    echo "main          - entries in ID: ${#ID[*]}"
fi
```

Output

```
fill_ids      - entries in ID: 5
main          - entries in ID: 0
```

Return value of `fill_fd` is not affecting anything either.

Comment: I tried replacing array with a  varible and same observation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are executing function in a subshell so it changes variable of child shell which is not visible in parent shell
culprit is "()"
you can debug it with printing shell id - see bellow:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Array to store debugger IDs
ID=()

echo $BASHPID
fill_id()
{
    for i in 1 2 3 4 5
    do
        ID+=( $i )
    done
echo $BASHPID
    echo "fill_ids      - entries in ID: ${#ID[*]}"
}


if  (fill_id)
then
    echo "main          - entries in ID: ${#ID[*]}"
fi
```

when you call function directly (without subshell) then it properly changes your variable.

Like this:

```
if fill_id
then
    echo "main          - entries in ID: ${#ID[*]}"
fi
```

Comment: Your explanation is good. You could also add a sample of the correct call of `fill_id` in the condition.

Answer (score 3):

Just don't execute the function in a subshell.

```
if fill_id
then
    echo "main          - entries in ID: ${#ID[*]}"
fi
```